# How to run Python (Flask) Server in Background?

Tags: python, flask, server

I want to run a local server which executes as specific script when a GET request to the IP is made,
because of that I need to run the server in the background (while a other script is runing too) without printing any stuff.
Here is my Code:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET'])
def index():
    return "Hello How are you?"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port = 5000)
```

I tried it with Threading but I always get stuck at this Output

When running this code I get this Output:

````
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://IP:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)```
````

Comment: Are you on Windows or Linux?

Comment: I'm on Windows 10

Comment: As this seems to be an issue during development only: What about opening another/additional terminal window so the two scripts are executed in parallel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `pythonw` to run the application in the background:

```
pythonw -m flask run > log.txt 2>&1
```

make sure the name of the Python file is `app.py`.